# how to get multiple row values in a single row for a corresponding column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this

```
table   | last_access  | last_read   | read_by  |  last_write  |  write_by |   last_str_change |   str_change_by

tab1    | 01-02-21     | 01-02-21    | user1    | null         | null      |  null            |  null
tab1    | 02-02-21     | null        | null     | 02-02-21     | user2     |  null            |  null
tab1    | 03-02-21     | null        | null     | null         | null      | 03-02-21         |  user3
```

i need it in this format

```
table    last_access   last_read   read_by   last_write   write_by    last_str_change    str_change_by
tab1     03-02-21      01-02-21    user1      02-02-21    user2       03-02-21           user3
```

the last_access column should have max or latest date from columns last_read,last_write,last_str_change and columns last_read,last_write,last_str_change data should come in a single row.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
select table, max(last_access), max(last_read), max(last_write), max(last_str_change)
from t
group by table;
```

Comment: Gordon, if a table has been read two times then we have two entries in last_read and last_read_by columns, in such cases how to pick the read_by column value with corresponding highest last_read column value.

Comment: @maseedilyas . . . This answers the question that was asked here.  If you have a more refined question, ask a *new* question.